# Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models.EventGridEvent isn't deserializable by a controller action

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-eventgrid

I'm writing a Controller Action to accept a Post request from a webhook in Azure EventGrid. The examples in the documentation manually parse the json from the HTTP request into a Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models.EventGridEvent object.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events

This seemed a little complicated to me and I thought that I should have been able to let .Net deseralize the Json for me. My understanding that .Net should deserialize a JSON object into the expected object of the action.

My Action is as follows.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<OkObjectResult> Post(EventGridEvent gridEvent)
    {
        var response = string.Empty;
        if (gridEvent.EventType == EventTypes.EventGridSubscriptionValidationEvent)
        {
            // Validate
            var eventData = (SubscriptionValidationEventData) gridEvent.Data;

            var responseData = new SubscriptionValidationResponse()
            {
                ValidationResponse = eventData.ValidationCode
            };

            return new OkObjectResult(responseData);
        }

        if (gridEvent.EventType == EventTypes.StorageBlobCreatedEvent)
        {
            var eventData = (StorageBlobCreatedEventData) gridEvent.Data;
            // Get File

            // Validate File

            // Dispatch Events
        }

        return new OkObjectResult(response);
    }
```

I'm sending a Post request to the Action via postman and using a sample body from the docs

```
[{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/Storage/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xstoretestaccount",
  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/testcontainer/blobs/testfile.txt",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
  "eventTime": "2017-06-26T18:41:00.9584103Z",
  "id": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e069631",
  "data": {
    "api": "PutBlockList",
    "clientRequestId": "6d79dbfb-0e37-4fc4-981f-442c9ca65760",
    "requestId": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e000000",
    "eTag": "0x8D4BCC2E4835CD0",
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "contentLength": 524288,
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "url": "https://example.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/testfile.txt",
    "sequencer": "00000000000004420000000000028963",
    "storageDiagnostics": {
      "batchId": "b68529f3-68cd-4744-baa4-3c0498ec19f0"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}]
```

I checked what the EventGridEvent object looks like and everything looks correct and the json mapps to the expected object

```
public class EventGridEvent
{
    public EventGridEvent()
    {
    }

    public EventGridEvent(
      string id,
      string subject,
      object data,
      string eventType,
      DateTime eventTime,
      string dataVersion,
      string topic = null,
      string metadataVersion = null)
    {
      ...
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "topic")]
    public string Topic { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public object Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "eventType")]
    public string EventType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "eventTime")]
    public DateTime EventTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "metadataVersion")]
    public string MetadataVersion { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dataVersion")]
    public string DataVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual void Validate()
    {
       ...
    }
  }
```

The only property that deserializes for me is eventTime and everything else is null

Comment: It may that the `data` in the json is a list and your application convert it to Object. Please define a custom object for it.

Comment: @JimXu I had tried that too and it didn't deserialize at all. It came true as an empty list

Answer (score 0):

this ended up being a simple issue. I had forgotten to add [FromBody] before the expected type.

so My controller action became

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<OkObjectResult> Post([FromBody]List<EventGridEvent> request)
{
  ...
}
```